# get active tab name into a hidden field at runtime

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have aspx page with tabs like below...

```
 <ul class="tabs-menu" style="list-style-type: none;" >
        <li class="active"><a class="anchor" href="#ATab" style="text-decoration: none;" > A</a></li>
        <li><a class="anchor" href="#BTab" style="text-decoration: none;">B</a></li>
        <li><a class="anchor" href="#CTab" style="text-decoration:none;">C</a></li>

    </ul>
```

This is the hidden field that should store the active tab and pass it to a function when clicked on submit button on Modal popup

```
<input type="hidden" name="findTab" id="findTabname" value=""/>
```

I am showing this ASPX page as Modal pop up from another page using Jquery like below

```
$("#Test").live('click', function OpenSearchDialog() {
        $("#dialog_testsearch").load("Test.aspx", function() {
          $(this).dialog({
              autoOpen: true,
              modal: true,
              width: 750,
              buttons: {
                  Go: function() {
                      var current_tab = $("#anchor").tabs('option', 'selected');
                   //anchor is my class for the list items
         callTestFunction()

                  },
                  Close: function() {
                      $(this).dialog("close");
                  }
              }
          });
          $(this).siblings('.ui-dialog-titlebar').remove();
          $(this).container.css('height', 'auto');
      });
      return false;
  });
```

Now My question is how do I get the name of active name into that hidden field ? And then into this Jquery when clicked on Go button..
Because I wanted to execute functions based on tabs selected

```
 function callTestFunction()
   {
       if A
        //do this
       if B 
       //do this
       if c 
        //do this 
    }
```

I am really hitting my head to the wall to this simple thing. But I couldn't get it working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it..

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
   $('#findTabname').val($('.tabs-menu li').index('.active'));
})
```

And when you want to use the value of the hidden input to active tabs back use..

```
$('.nav-tabs li:eq($('#findTabname').val()) a').tab('show');
```

Comment: I have updated my question to make it understand that Modal pop up script is from different ASPX and my tabs are in different ASPX

Answer (score 2):

You can script like:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    var valnew = $(".tabs-menu").find(".active a").html();
    $('#findTabname').val(valnew);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If `anchor` is a class you should use `.anchor` as opposed to `#anchor` as a jQuery selector. The hash sign - # - make jQuery to believe it searches for an element with an ID of anchor.

Further, you can listen for the click event on the `.anchor` elements and in the handler store the value of `href` attribute into the hidden field, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(anchor).on("click", )
});

function anchor_Click() {
    var hf = $(findTabname);
    hf.val($(this).attr("href"));
}
```

This way you'll have `#ATab`/`#BTab`/`#CTab` in your hidden field.

Comment: oopss... this.attr is not a function is the error I get.

Comment: oops indeed. I forgot to select `this` with jQuery first; now I corrected the code example.